Confusion regarding Total Probability
Question: A purse contains 4 silver and 5 copper coins. A second purse contains 3 silver and 7 copper coins. If a coin is taken out at random from one of the purses, what is the probability it's a copper coin?
Now, while trying to answer such a question, I think that logically,the answer should be the sum of the conditional probability that 'a copper coin is taken out if purse 1 is chosen'[P(C|P1)] and 'a copper coin is taken out if purse 2 is chosen'[P(C|P2)].
But, the answer will be the sum of the probability that 'copper coin is chosen from Purse 1' and 'copper coin is chosen from Purse 2':
P(C intersect P1)+P(C intersect P2)
= P(P1).P(C|P1) + P(P2).P(C|P2)
= (1/2)(5/9) + (1/2)(7/10)
= 113/180
If someone could clarify this so that it is easy to understand, I would be very happy. Thanks in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$P(P_1)*P(C|P_1) ) + P(P_2)*P(C|P_2)$

@trueblueanil I know this, but why is the answer not the sum of the conditional probabilities that I mentioned in the question

The answer generated by the comment of true blue anil will be correct.  Why not edit your posted question to explicitly show all of the work, show the computed answer, and then specify what the official answer is?

I like to think of this as two different probabilities. Here's how I think of it:
If you select the first purse the probability of getting a copper coin is 5 coppers out of 9 total, so the probability is 5/9.
If you select the second purse the probability of getting a copper coin is 7 coppers out of 10 total, so the probability is 7/10.
Because each purse is no more likely to be picked it is a 50/50 percent chance. There are two ways to get a copper coin, pull one out of the first purse, or pull one out of the second purse. The combined probability will be the sum of these two chances.
The probability of pulling one out of the first purse. Is 1/2 (The probability of choosing the first purse) times 5/9 (the probability of getting a copper coin from the first purse) so the total is 5/18.
The probability of pulling one out of the second purse. Is 1/2 (The probability of choosing the second purse) times 7/10 (the probability of getting a copper coin from the second purse) so the total is 7/20.
The final answer will be if either one of these happens so we add the probabilities. Doing this we get 5/18 + 7/20 = 113/180.
If you don't want to do the whole 1/2 thing you can take the average of the first two probabilities. Hope this helped!

Before you take a coin out of a purse, you first have to pick a purse.
So, you need to include the probability of that happening in the terms of the series.
$\qquad\begin{align}\Bbb P(C)&=\Bbb P(C\cap(P_1\cup P_2))&&\text{coin may be in either purse}\\[1ex]&=\Bbb P((C\cap P_1)\cup(C\cap P_2))&&\text{via distribution}\\[1ex]&= \Bbb P(C\cap P_1)+\Bbb P(C\cap P_2)&&\text{probability of a union of disjoint events}\\[1ex]&=\Bbb P(C\mid P_1)\,\Bbb P(P_1)+\Bbb P(C\mid P_2)\,\Bbb P(P_2)&&\text{definiion of conditional probability}\end{align}$
